# Retrieving data from infusionsoft to DOMO using plain javascript

Tags: javascript, xml-rpc, infusionsoft, domo

I am trying to create  custom connector in DOMO to retrieve data from infusionsoft. I can use only plain javascript in DOMO IDE. The below code is what I wrote to make request to XML-RPC Api of infusionsoft but I am getting fault code response. Xmlhttprequest are not supported in DOMO Ide.

```
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'+
'<methodCall>'+
  '<methodName>DataService.query</methodName>'+
  '<params>'+
    '<param>'+
      '<value><string>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</string></value>'+
    '</param>'+
    '<param>'+
      '<value><string>Invoice</string></value>'+
    '</param>'+
    '<param>'+
      '<value><int>1000</int></value>'+
    '</param>'+
    '<param>'+
      '<value><int>0</int></value>'+
    '</param>'+
    '<param>'+
      '<value><struct>'+
        '<member><name>Id</name>'+
          '<value><string>[1,2,3,4]</string></value>'+
        '</member>'+
      '</struct></value>'+
    '</param>'+
    '<param>'+
      '<value><array>'+
        '<data>'+
          '<value><string>Id</string></value>'+
          '</data>'+
      '</array></value>'+
    '</param>'+
    '<param>'+
      '<value><string>orderBy</string></value>'+
    '</param>'+
    '<param>'+
      '<value><boolean>ascending</boolean></value>'+
    '</param>'+
  '</params>'+
'</methodCall>';
httprequest.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
httprequest.addParameter('xml', xml);

var res = httprequest.post('https://api.infusionsoft.com/crm/xmlrpc/v1?access_token='+metadata.account.accesstoken);
    DOMO.log(res)
```

The response which I am getting is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><methodResponse><fault><value><struct><member><name>faultCode</name><value><i4>0</i4></value></member><member><name>faultString</name><value>Failed to parse XML-RPC request: Content is not allowed in prolog.</value></member></struct></value></fault></methodResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Content is not allowed in prolog" error means you are transmitting something before the XML declaration. Because you are adding the XML body as a parameter, the request is being submitted as `"xml=" + xml`.

Just pass the xml as the second parameter to the post request.

```
httprequest.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
var res = httprequest.post('https://api.infusionsoft.com/crm/xmlrpc/v1?access_token='+metadata.account.accesstoken, xml);
```